# spring based bundle in apache felix osgi

Tags: spring-mvc, osgi, apache-felix

I am working one POC where I want to create plugin based web application. Main application will have all the spring mvc context. Plugins can write spring controllers but they cannot have their own spring context file. What I want is when plugin is installed all its controller is scanned (plugins controller need to be in specific package so for that package component scan will be defined in parent context) and ready to use. I am able achieve the installation part however when I am trying to access bundle/plugin controller end point through rest call I get no mapping found error.
Has anyone tried something like this? It will be great if I can get reference to some example.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Probably Virgo Snaps is the framework you are looking for? 
https://www.eclipse.org/virgo/documentation/virgo-documentation-3.5.0.RELEASE/docs/snaps-guide/htmlsingle/virgo-snaps-guide.html

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the spring part, I've already done this with
a) Apache Wicket and Pax Wicket
b) Vaadin

For a) you might want to look at the [Apache Karaf WebConsole](http://karaf.apache.org/index/subprojects/webconsole.html).
For b) take a look at this rather "old" [showcase](https://github.com/ANierbeck/osgi-vaadin-demo) of mine.

Both of those showcases use either standard OSGi services or Blueprint for the services (http-services) and the discovery of new "web-components" or views.